# How to jump to any Cell in a UICollectionView by using a custom layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 40 cells in my horizontal UICollectionView and a button.

I can jump from cell number 5 to cell number 10 when I click on the button.

But as soon as I want to go to a further cell ( for example from 5 to 25 ),

it doesn't work, and instead it goes to 0.

code:

```
func setValue(value: Int, animated: Bool) {
   self.value = value
   if let row = find(values, value) {
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
   selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? StepperCell
   collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: animated)
  }
 }

override func prepareLayout() {
   let start = Int(collectionView!.bounds.size.width * 0.5) - statics.width / 2
   let length = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)

if cache.isEmpty && length > 0 {
   for item in 0..<length {
     let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
     let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
     attributes.frame = CGRect(
      x: start + (statics.width + statics.padding) * indexPath.item,
      y: 0,
      width: statics.width,
      height: statics.height
    )
    cache.append(attributes)
  }
  contentWidth = CGRectGetMaxX(cache.last!.frame) + CGFloat(start)
   }
 }

 override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
   var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
   for attributes in cache {
      if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect) {
        layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
    }
  }
  return layoutAttributes
  }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will return `nil` if the cell is not displayed. But that should not prevent the collectionView from scrolling.

Comment: It does scroll if i'm 5 cells away, but if I'm on number 5 and I want to go to 25 by pressing on the Btn , It doesn't work.

Comment: But do you have 25 items in collectionView? What returns numberOfItemsInSection(_:) ?

Comment: Make sure the if statement is being executed when you try from 5 to 25, throw a log or a breakpoint in there.

Comment: @AndreiLuca it returns 41

Comment: hmm. print your row integer to output to check if is less than 41.

Comment: it's 25, should I get UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

Comment: do you have a custom Layout? check attributes to see where frame is located

Comment: @AndreiLuca  
Yes I have a custom Layout , the frame is located in ( x = 197, y = 0 )

Comment: Well I think the frames for some cells are wrong, in my opinion cell 25 should have a greater x value. The scroll is working and is scrolling at wrong frame. Try to fix frames

Comment: @AndreiLuca When I override the function `layoutAttributesforElementsInRect` and then print the `layoutAttributes` it returns 9 values ( I guess that is  the problem )

Comment: well this method should not return attributes for all cells, it gives you a rectangle which is approximate your screen rectangle, and you return the attributes only for cells that should be viewed.

Comment: override prepareLayout function and make all the math there, calculate attributes for all your cells, supplementary, decorative views, keep them in an array or dictionary, and in layoutAttributesforElementsInRect you just go foreach attribute you calculated and check if cell/suplim/decorat view intersects that rect, if do, create an array with all that intersect and return

Comment: @AndreiLuca I have already did that , maybe the mistake is there ( I've updated my code )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84060/discussion-between-andrei-luca-and-azicode).

Comment: I downloaded the code and it works ... without any problems.. the collection view scrolls correctly to the cell which i pass to the `setValue:animated:` method...

Comment: Yes but if you pass a higher value it doesn't work properly. 35 or 33

Comment: It seem to work fine, where do you mean that 35 or 33 should be put ?

Comment: oh nevermind, actually it works because I updated the code and resolved the problem. I will post an answer with the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, and some help from a fellow coder. I came up  with a simpler and more effective solution.
I use custom layout only for the snapping effect (when switching between cells), and then I let the flow layout handle the rest.
here is the code :

```
struct Statics {  
   static let width = CGFloat(50.0)  
   static let height = CGFloat(50.0)  
   static let padding = CGFloat(5.0)  
}  

func commonInit() {  
   ...  
   // I had to set layout from the code, didn't work from the Interface Builder  
    let layout = HorizontalLayout()  
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal  
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout  
    collectionView.dataSource = self  
}  

override func layoutSubviews() {  
    super.layoutSubviews()  

    // Set item size, line spacing and insets and let the flow layout do the rest  
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! HorizontalLayout  
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: Statics.width, height: Statics.height)  
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = Statics.padding  
    let sideMargin = (collectionView.bounds.width - Statics.width) / 2.0  
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, sideMargin, 0.0, sideMargin)  

    setValue(value, animated: true)  
}  

 class HorizontalLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {  
   // This the only method you need to override  
    override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {  
     let contentOffset: CGPoint  
     let itemWidth = itemSize.width  
     let padding = minimumLineSpacing  

    // Calculate nearest cell from the proposed content offset  
    let index = round(proposedContentOffset.x / (itemWidth + padding))  
    let x = (itemWidth + padding) * index  
    contentOffset = CGPoint(x: x, y: proposedContentOffset.y)  

    return contentOffset  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can dispense with the row logic. After all - you are just using the passed `Int`. If your `if let` clause fails, it won't scroll.

Also, drop the call to `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - you do not need it (you are not using it either).

I guess that perhaps you should use `NSIndexPath(forItem, inSection)` rather than `NSIndexPath(forRow, inSection)`. (Table view uses *row*, collectionView uses *item*.)

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(
      NSIndexPath(forItem: value, inSection: 0), 
      atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: You are using a custom layout which you did not even mention in your question. It works as expected by setting the Layout to "Flow" and Scroll Direction to "Horizontal". It was to be expected that it would not work with a vertical layout.

Comment: Actually VerticalLayout is just a typo in the class name. And when I set layout to "Flow" and scrolling direction to "Horizontal" I lose the snapping effect that is implemented in my class "VerticalLayout" which in fact should be named "HorizontalLayout".

Comment: I could also fix it by adding `self.scrollDirection = .Horizontal` in  `prepareLayout()`. Time to accept the answer;-)

Comment: I also needed to disable the `collectionViewContentSize()` implementation. This is likely where you error is.

Comment: Do you know how I could fix the implementation of `collectionViewContentSize()`?